# Tablas de multiplicar en horizontal c++

Tags: c++

necesito ayuda con este problema:

**Diseñe la siguiente clase para mostrar varias tablas a la vez de manera horizontal**

```
class TablasMultiplicar{

  int TablaIni, TablaFin;

  public:
    void PedirNoTablas(); 
    /*
      Método para solicitar por teclado el número de la tabla de
      multiplicar inicial y final a ser mostradas. Si el valor introducido 
      en ambos atributos 
    */

    void MostrarTablas(); 
      /*
        es menor que uno o mayor que 10, el método volverá a
        solicitar ambos números de tabla.
        En el caso que el valor de TablaIni sea menor que TablaFin, el 
        método deberá intercambiarlos
      */
};
```

**Asi es como tiene que quedar:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto me sale si hago la tabla del 1 al 2:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y esto es lo que me sale si pongo la tabla del 1 al 3 por ejemplo:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Por ahora hace solo dos tablas en horizontal, si tiene que hacer mas de dos se desordena. Tengo hecho esto:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class TablasMultiplicar{

int TablaIni, TablaFin;

public:

void PedirNoTablas();  /*Método para solicitar por teclado el número de la tabla de
                       multiplicar inicial y final a ser mostradas. Si el valor introducido en ambos atributos */

void MostrarTablas();  /*es menor que uno o mayor que 10, el método volverá a
                        solicitar ambos números de tabla.
                        En el caso que el valor de TablaIni sea menor que TablaFin, el método deberá
                        intercambiarlos*/

};

void TablasMultiplicar::PedirNoTablas(){

do{

cout<<"Introduzca el numero de la tabla de multiplicar inicial: ";cin>>TablaIni;
cout<<"\nIntroduzca el numero de la tabla de multiplicar final: ";cin>>TablaFin;

}while(((TablaIni <1 || TablaIni>10)||(TablaFin < 1 || TablaFin >10 )));

}

void TablasMultiplicar::MostrarTablas(){





for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){

cout<<TablaIni<<" x "<<i<<" = "<<TablaIni*i<<"\t";



    for(int j=(TablaIni+1);j<=TablaFin;j++){


        cout<<j<<" x "<<i<<" = "<<j*i<<"\n";



        }
       }


    }









int main()
{

    TablasMultiplicar tablas;

    tablas.PedirNoTablas();

    tablas.MostrarTablas();








    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Las acabo de agregar.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema.. que se llama cortes de control...

Tus for estan mal...

lo que tenes que hacer es, imprimir multiplicar por 0, la cantidad de tablas que tengas... y despues cuando terminas eso, imprimir el salto de linea.

```
//ahora imprimimos las tablas.. primero por fila, y despues los saltos
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    for(int j=(TablaIni+1);j<=TablaFin;j++)
    {
        cout<<j<<" x "<<i<<" = "<<j*i<<"\t";
    }
    //cuando ya imprimimos las tablas, ponemos el salto de linea
   cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero en realidad no estaban mal, solo me faltaba el cout<<endl; del final. Lo he puesto y ha funcionado perfecto. Gracias :D